# jQuery: Can't update text in a div using $.post

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get some text to display in a `div`. This `div` will appear many times on the page so targeting an ID is out.

**This works: it displays the message in the div.**

```
$('.join-div .content a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings('.message').html('THIS IS A TEST');
});
```

**This does not**

```
$('.join-div .content a').click(function() {

    var data = 'foo=bar';

    $.post('/assets/ajax/join.php',data, function(response) {
        $(this).parent().siblings('.message').html('THIS IS A TEST');
    });
});
```

I'm not receiving any errors in the console and the php script works; it returns a response and I can `alert()` it. It looks like `$.post` is interfering somehow but I can't figure it out.

Comment: is ajax call successful??

Comment: I think $(this) is no longer in the proper scope inside of the ajax call. Try using the full selector instead.

Comment: Most likely, `this` is being re-bound by the time the AJAX callback fires. Try using `var target=$(this);` and `target.parent().siblings('.message').html('THIS IS A TEST');`

Comment: @KjeldSchmidt is right

Comment: yes, i've stated that at the bottom of the post. i can alert the response.

Comment: var data = 'foo:bar';

Comment: how do i go about marking this as solved? i don't want to take credit for IMSoP's answer.

Comment: I already closed it as duplicate. There is nothing you have to do anymore, unless you disagree that this is a duplicate and want to reopen the question.